# How to use the type "expandable" correctly?

Tags: json, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

## Question

How to use the type "expandable" correctly?

### Description

I have a batch that runs every hour and sends some stats to our slack. Each `JSON` output can be quite large and I'm looking for a way to have it collapsable/expandable.

I was playing with slack's [BlockKit Builder](https://api.slack.com/block-kit) in hopes that there was something of the sort, and I came across (when looking at the message errors) that there is a type called `expandable`.

However, there is no (?) documentation regarding it. The only thing that I know is.

1. It requires a `blocks` property
2. It *should* be a child of a `blocks` property

### What I've tried

I went on [the block builder (demo)](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=message&blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22expandable%22%2C%22blocks%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Hello%2C%20Assistant%20to%20the%20Regional%20Manager%20Dwight!%20*Michael%20Scott*%20wants%20to%20know%20where%20you%27d%20like%20to%20take%20the%20Paper%20Company%20investors%20to%20dinner%20tonight.%5Cn%5Cn%20*Please%20select%20a%20restaurant%3A*%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D) and was able to get this to not throw any errors but there was no visual output...

```
{
   "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "expandable",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "Hello, Assistant to the Regional Manager Dwight! *Michael Scott* wants to know where you'd like to take the Paper Company investors to dinner tonight.\n\n *Please select a restaurant:*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### What I would like:

I would like to have a working collapsable/expandable and understand what the different properties are and how they work.

Comment: The feature you are talking about is undocumented at best and most likely not available to third party devs. Can you please add the source of your "find" to clarify?

Comment: Btw. if you need an expandable text field, take a look at secondary attachments. They will only show the first 10 lines of a text by default and hide the rest under a more "Show More" button.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken if you go on the builder and set the "type" to an empty string, the parser will notify you that it's expection one of the following "section", ..., ..., "expandable" which interested me. Yes, I noticed the seconday attachments but it doesn't solve the issue. I would like to hide certain sections that are deemed "not super important" and show only those that are important.